# Discrepancies between Analytics and Shopify sessions

Tags: google-analytics, shopify

I've been looking at my statistics and lately, I found a difference between the number of sessions in Google Analytics and Shopify.

Google Analytics reports 20% fewer sessions than Shopify...The implementation between Analytics and Shopify seems to be ok, as there isn't any duplicate code or tag.

Do you know how I can solve this?

I've read some similar questions but I haven't found an answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons for differences in tracking results:

- Differences in how page reloads and unique visitors are counted. Google counts every page reload, but a browser doesn't count reloads of cached pages.
- Differences in how sessions are defined. For example, some analytics software counts search bots as visitors, while other software doesn’t.
- Google can only count visitors with JavaScript and cookies enabled. Some visitors might not allow cookies or JavaScript.
- Customers can use browser extensions to block Google Analytics from tracking their sessions and purchases.
- Discrepancies might be introduced because of different reporting time zones. Read about changing your Google time zone here.
- It’s unlikely that identical tracking mechanisms are being used by each of the services, so your visitors aren't recorded equally. Details of recording mechanisms are proprietary information and are never shared.